# cloudera navigator insert overwrite directory

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-navigator

I am trying to insert file from table to one of the hdfs directory. It does transfer successfully and create the file. but, i am unable to see the data lineage on the cloudera navigator.

I am posting my command below can anyone help what could be the issue, is with the syntax or we have to configure some setting into the navigator.

Syntax:

```
insert overwrite directory '/user/demo/test_demo' select age, id from demo1;
```

Also, on the web portal of known issues they mentioned that it should show.
Link: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/release-notes/topics/cn_rn_known_issues.html#hive_hue

Answer (score 0):

As the above query comes under operation execution. when you copy the above query in navigator search bar and from filters select operation execution you would be able to see the data lineage.

If you search for the result based on the out put directory it won't show anything as it a hive operation execution !